# Shortening Ajax Code

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am creating fully Ajax based website so all actions calls a different JS function therefore I am using this Ajax Code in each of my function which makes my functions a big code.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        var getData=xmlhttp.responseText;
        if(getData=="something") {
            /* 
            code goes here
            */
        }
        else {
            /* 
            code goes here
            */
        }
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","mypage.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

So I wanted to ask should I use a different function that contains only above Ajax Code and declare my variable getData globally so whenever I need it I should call it.

**Here is how I wanted to use**

```
var getData=""; /*declaring var Globally (I read it like this dont know right)*/

function oneAjax(checkPage) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            getData=xmlhttp.responseText;
            /*now check further in the function which called it*/
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",checkPage+".php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Will it create any conflict with other running actions?
or provide me any right solution for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not going to use an off-the-shelf library, you should pass a "callback" to `oneAjax`:

```
function oneAjax(checkPage, done, fail) {

     ...

     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
             if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                 done(xmlhttp.responseText, xmlhttp.status);
             } else {
                 fail(xmlhttp.status);
             }
          }
     };

 }
```

Adjust the parameters passed to the callbacks to suit your requirements.

To use:

```
oneAjax('mypage', function(text, status) {
    // success
    console.log(status);
}, function(status) {
    // failure
    console.log(status);
});
```

Comment: Maybe provide an example of how `oneAjax` should be called. I think callbacks might be confusing for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use Jquery or something like this? Such library will much shorten your statements and this will be much easier to write.

But still if you want to do it by your own you should read about javascript promises. On msdn there is a nice tutorial how to solve your problem: [Asynchronous Programming in JavaScript with “Promises”](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/11/asynchronous-programming-in-javascript-with-promises.aspx)

Comment: + 1 for the tutorial, not so happy about the usual "Y u no jquery?"

Comment: jQuery is not a silver bullet.

Comment: @FelixKling it is good for shooting oneself in the foot, though ;-)

Comment: @GonçaloVieira I know that Jquery is not a "silver bullet" but sometimes write your own code when there exist tested library looks like waste of time

Comment: how can it be a waste of time if it enables you to understand what's going on behind that library?

most people that use jQuery don't care, nor know, what's happening behind the scenes, if he's learning about javascript, doing the direct approach to the language will be more beneficial to him in the long run.

Comment: @Alnitak: Made me laugh :)

Comment: FWIW, the AJAX parts of jQuery are the one bit I can't do without :)

Comment: yes yes @Garath i want to use, but dont know how to use Jquery or something like this :( , plz provide me a code in jquery that fits my need

Comment: @AbarChoudhary there are really many tutorials on how to do this. For example above which I linked in orginal post. One more really good is this one: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

I think using the jQuery library would be better and provide a better low level abstraction

```
<!-- add a protocol if on local ex: http: -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

It also offers features like JSONP to get around cross domain issues

Comment: JSONP is nothing specific to jQuery though. JSONP is nothing else than defining a function, creating a `script` element and attaching to the document.

Comment: Yeah but it has this functionality already and you don't have to code it point being. jQuery already has a ton of functionality coded with cross browser compatibility.

Comment: Sure, but it sounded like you could do something with jQuery that you couldn't do without. I totally agree that it is easier with it.